# '+' Symbols Moved to a Wrong Position in Case of Arabic on Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, locale, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on an app where I have a TextView where I set a country code like **'+1'**. It works fine for both Arabic and English below Oreo, but when I run it on Android Oreo the country code is shown like **'1+'**

[image: Below Oreo it works fine]

This is the case where it works fine and it is for below Oreo devices.

[image: In case of Oreo it looks wrong]

On Oreo it looks like this.

Do any one knows how to fix this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, in Arabic, you read from right to left, and Oreo might use this to move the `+`. I think you might want to add an if else condition for Oreo.

Comment: this works fine for all devices below Oreo, issue is only on Oreo devices, may be some structural changes leads to this on Oreo

Comment: @ZubairAkber I am also facing the same issue in my client App, also looking for the solution

Comment: @Zubai Akber Hmmm... Not really sure. In many cases you can add a condition. I used this code to make the toolbar transparent in one of my activities:  `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
                w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }`

Comment: @Kemo this is for toolBar but this issue only seems in Android Oreo, it works fine for the rest of devices